# Javascript function - converting string argument to operator

Tags: javascript, function, arguments, operators

*Apologies if my question is unclear, wasn't sure how to word it!*

I'm trying to create a function that takes two numbers and a string which contains an operator (e.g. '+', '-', '*', '/').

I've used .valueOf() on the string to extract the operator, however the num1 and num2 arguments do not seem to evaluate to the passed number parameters. Why is this happening?

```
function calculate(num1, operator, num2) {
  return `num1 ${operator.valueOf()} num2`;
}
undefined


calculate(2, '+', 1);
"num1 + num2"         //result
```

Comment: You cannot do what you're trying to do without using `eval()` or `new Function()`, unless you directly examine the operator parameter and programmatically act on it as appropriate.

Comment: @Pointy ...but eval() is not an evil..... I believe a switch can do the work.

Comment: @gaetanoM and the switch would be what the second part of that comment is referring too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your requirements, you could use `eval()` to achieve this:

```
function calculate(num1, operator, num2) {
  return eval(`${num1} ${operator} ${num2}`);
}

console.log(calculate(2, '+', 1)); // 3
```

Alternatively, you could avoid the use of `eval()` by using a switch block, which [would make your code easier to debug and potentially more secure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea):

```
function calculate(num1, operator, num2) {
  switch (operator.trim()) { // Trim possible white spaces to improve reliability
    case '+':
      return num1 + num2
    case '-':
      return num1 - num2
    case '/':
      return num1 / num2
    case '*':
      return num1 * num2
  }
}

console.log(calculate(2, '+', 1)); // 3
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do what you want is with an object that maps operator names to functions.

```js
const opmap = {
  "+": (x, y) => x + y,
  "-": (x, y) => x - y,
  "*": (x, y) => x * y,
  "/": (x, y) => x / y,
};

function calculate(num1, operator, num2) {
  if (operator in opmap) {
    return opmap[operator](num1, num2);
  }
}

console.log(calculate(2, '+', 1));
```