# In JavaScript, how can I create one function that takes two numbers and a mathematical operator + - / * perform a calculation with the given numbers

Tags: javascript, function, calculator

Just starting learn js, how can I get results like what shows in the examples.

So the require is like this:

Create a function that takes two numbers and a mathematical operator + - / * and will perform a calculation with the given numbers.

Examples

calculator(2, "+", 2) ➞ 4

calculator(2, "*", 2) ➞ 4

calculator(4, "/", 2) ➞ 2

Notes

If the input tries to divide by 0, return: "Can't divide by 0!"

```
function calculator (a, b) {
  let output = 0;
  output = a+b;
  return output;
}
console.log(calculator(2,2));
```

Here is what I wrote, only for performing "+".

I thought maybe I should try to add another parameter to repersent "+*/", but I can't get it right.

Anyone can help with it?
Thanks

Comment: You could even try to implement a function taking three parameters ...

Comment: [Duplicate](https://google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+function+that+takes+two+numbers+and+operator) of [Javascript function - converting string argument to operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52086419/4642212).

Answer (score 3):

This should work

```
function calculator (a, b, c) {
  let output = 0;

  try {

    switch(c) {
      case '+':
        output = a + b
        break;

      case '*':
        output = a * b
        break;

      case '-':
        output = a - b
        break;

     case '/': 
        if (b === 0) {
          throw "Can't divide by 0!"
        } else {
          output = a / b
        }
        break;
    }
  }
  catch(e) {
    console.log("There's an error: ", e)
  }

  return output;
}

console.log(calculator(2,2,'*'));
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know a great way to write this!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the function:

```js
const calculator = (a, b, operation) => {
  if (operation === '+') return a + b;
  if (operation === '-') return a - b;
  if (operation === '*') return a * b;
  if (operation === '/') return b === 0 ? "Can't divide by 0!" : a / b;
}

console.log(calculator(10, 10, "*"));
```

Comment: It's not a good method to use `eval`.. it can leads to serious security risks. Not a good advice for a beginner..

Comment: It's really helpful!! Thanks